# Не срабатывает window.open

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, google-chrome, blob

Простая функция, которой передаётся объект `blob`:

```
output_blob(data) {
  window.open(URL.createObjectURL(data));
}
```

Окно не открывается в `Google Chrome версии 75.0.3770.100 (Официальная сборка),  (64 бит)` на `OS Ubuntu 18.04`. **Не выводится никаких ошибок!** интересно ещё и то, что вот так срабатывает:

```
output_blob(data) {
  window.open();
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @oox911 может проблема в том что Вы не указали перед именем function ?

Comment: @Leks — это `Vue` метод.

Comment: @oox911 ясно, тогда извините

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всплывающее окно блокируется либо браузером, либо расширением для браузера.

**1** Пример из практики.

```
<!-- Где-то в шаблоне компонента. -->
Экспорт файла <i>.*csv</i> по <a href="#" @click="exportToCsv">ссылке</a>.
```

```
// Где-то в поле `methods` компонента.
exportToCsv(event) {
  let csvContent = ...;

  let url = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([csvContent], {
      type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
    })
  );

  event.target.setAttribute('href', url);
  event.target.setAttribute('download', '997553.csv');
}
```

---

**2** Или решение "в лоб": **`window.location = url;`**.

---

**3** Если по каким-то причинам все-таки нужно всплывающее окно:

```
output_blob(data) {
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(data);

  let newWindow = window.open();

  newWindow.onload = function() {
    newWindow.location = url;
  }
}
```

Comment: Я принял ваш ответ, но проблема была проще, был включен `Adblock Plus`

Comment: `либо расширением для браузера`: Adblock Plus - это расширение

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сделать так

```
let bind=null

    output_blob(data) {
      bind = data
      url  = URL.createObjectURL(bind)
      return window.open(url);
    }
```

или

```
output_blob(data) {
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(data)
  function inject(){
      return URL.createObjectURL(url);
  }
  return window.open(inject());
}
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, а где тут замыкание?

Comment: в переменной которая внутри функции output_blob

Comment: Да, туплю. Не помогло.